# How can I open a folder of APK files and decompile it automatically using APKtool?

Tags: android, apktool

APKtool allows you to decompile an APK file one by one but I am trying to open a folder with 500 APKs and decompile them automatically without having to manually enter each file name. How can I do this in python?

Comment: you can write a small script, maybe using python or whatever you are comfortable & use `for` loop to iterate & decompile all the apks.

Comment: I'm extremely new to python. What is the line of code to decompile all the apks using apktool?

Comment: You can check the docs: https://ibotpeaches.github.io/Apktool/documentation/